# NestJS (Nx workspace) build failing on Heroku

Tags: heroku, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to deploy a NestJS app (in Nx workspace) on Heroku, but the deploy is failing with error:

```
2021-12-24T11:03:17.280952+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/definitions.factory.js:26:38
2021-12-24T11:03:17.280953+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2021-12-24T11:03:17.280953+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.createForClass (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/definitions.factory.js:25:86)
2021-12-24T11:03:17.280954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.createForClass (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/schema.factory.js:9:75)
2021-12-24T11:03:17.280954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.89 (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:4717)
2021-12-24T11:03:17.280954+00:00 app[web.1]:     at o (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:12427)
2021-12-24T11:03:17.280955+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.812 (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:5865)
2021-12-24T11:03:17.280955+00:00 app[web.1]:     at o (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:12427)
2021-12-24T11:03:17.424198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-24T11:03:17.602083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have seen some Mongoose [issues](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5845#issuecomment-736865214) and they don't seem to be the problem here, since the packages have since gotten multiple updates.

Edit:

After running the app from the Heroku console I got a more explicit error:

```
/app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/definitions.factory.js:43
            optionsOrType = isClass ? optionsOrType : optionsOrType();
                                                      ^

TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Function.inspectTypeDefinition (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/definitions.factory.js:43:55)
    at Function.inspectTypeDefinition (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/definitions.factory.js:52:39)
    at /app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/definitions.factory.js:26:38
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.createForClass (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/definitions.factory.js:25:86)
    at Function.createForClass (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/factories/schema.factory.js:9:75)
    at Object.89 (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:4301)
    at o (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:12011)
    at Object.812 (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:5449)
    at o (/app/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:12011)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was caused by an upgrade of [nrwl/nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) to 13.3.1.
A downgrade of nrwl/nx to 13.2.4 fixed it.

So it seems that nx [13.3.0](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/releases/tag/13.3.0) introduced a dependency update which breaks the application.